# nrwl NX , angular , nest project, how to make PWA for a specific angular app

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am building a monorepo using NX nrwl. I have an angular front end and a nestjs backend in the same repository..

To make the angular project to PWA, there is command with ng-add, but that doesn't seem to be working with nx monorepo.. So How to properly configure PWA for angular app in the nx monorepo.

Looking for tutorials or tips or any links ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to install @angular/pwa

`npm install @angular/pwa --save-dev`

After that add with nx

`nx g @angular/pwa:ng-add --project your-project-name`

If nx is not install globally, you can use following instead.

`npx nx g @angular/pwa:ng-add --project your-project-name`